# Python Scraping for Section in Webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** News website for learning but i got situation

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

req = urlopen('https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/evidence-of-chidambaram-meeting-mukerjeas-destroyed-cbi/articleshow/71337533.cms')

page_html = req.read()

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html,"html.parser")

section = page_soup.find('section',{'class':'_2suu5  clearfix id-r-component 
undefined undefined '})

print(section)
```

i had already tried to **scrape** another site. code was working fine. but this time error was undefinable .

Comment: i was trying to scrap section tag in page

Comment: What is `error`?

Comment: not generating output at all .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it for you. I hope you learned something useful.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/evidence-of-chidambaram-meeting-mukerjeas-destroyed-cbi/articleshow/71337533.cms'
response = requests.get(url)

bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

#this will work too
#section = bs.find_all('section', class_='_2suu5 clearfix id-r-component undefined undefined')

section = bs.find_all('section', attrs={'class': '_2suu5 clearfix id-r-component undefined undefined'})

#print(section)
```

Comment: i am very glad that people like ever help me for such problem, i  am very thankful for your help.